# MATLAB run length encode

Tags: matlab, compression

I've found many solutions on how to do run length encoding with 1D array.
But what if I have a `4x4` array where it can be any numbers.

ie. `image = [1 2 3 3; 3 3 2 1; 4 4 2 5; 2 0 9 1];`

Should I remove the "`;`" and just make it into a single array? Or I can't do that?

My aim now is to do run length encoding to find the [value, run] and reconstruct the image back.

I know how it works theoretically but I can't seem to get the logic in matlab.

Objective:

> Given 4 x 4 array with random numbers,  Do run length coding for
>   compression, Reconstruct back the image with the compressed values.

Answer (score 0):

not quite sure if I get your objective right, 
I just give the answers based on my understanding

If you are trying to find the length of a matrix, e.g. a 4x4 array

```
    a=ones(4);
    len_a=length(a);
    disp(len_a); % screen print
```

that would screen print the length, 
note that length of the array is the maximum of column length and  raw length
e.g. a 4x5 array length() result is 5

if you are trying to find the mean value of this 4x4 array

```
a=ones(4);
mean_a=mean(a(:));
disp(mean_a);
```

that will give you the mean value of all elements in array a